# How to add Custom Field in "summary view" of Blog on Public Site Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am Using SharePoint 2013 Public Site not Blog Site.

According to requirement I Need to Customize Sharepoint 2013 Public Site Blog "Summary View" by showing a new custom column of video.

As Per Research i get result in Sharepoint 2010 Only not SP2013.

I also tried by doing these thing but not work :-(

1.Download Blog.xsl via SiteCollection URL/_layouts/xsl/blog.xsl.

2.Change according to the requirement Just Add xml snippet in Blog.xsl nothing             else.and save CustomBlog.xsl.

3.Edit Post section Of The Blog Page.

4.Select "Summary View" and in XSL section Provide Path of CustomBlog.xsl.

```html
<!--Start Blog for Video -->
<div class="Video">
    <xsl:for-each select="$Fields">
        <xsl:if test="@Name='VideoThumbnail' and not ($thisNode/@VideoThumbnail='')">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">:&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="$Fields[@Name='VideoThumbnail']" mode="Computed_body"><xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</div>
<!--End Blog for Video -->
```

Research URL:

http://sympmarc.com/2012/04/04/customizing-the-display-of-a-sharepoint-2010-blog/

Please help me out How to Customize summary view of Blog in Sharepoint 2013.

Thanks,

Satyam